# Tess4J - Native library (linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path

Tags: pdf, tesseract, ghostscript, tess4j

I'm using Tess4J (JNA wrapper around tesseract), and trying to call `tess.doOCR(myFile)` to OCR text from a single-page PDF.

I have GhostScript installed (by using `yum install ghostscript`), `gs -h` works correctly.

My app server is using `64-bit JVM`, and I have `gsdll64.dll`, and the 64-bit tesseract dll's `liblept168.dll` and `libtesseract302.dll` in the class path.

When `tess.doOCR(myFile)` is called, this is logged:

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
```

But then it just stops there. The program doesn't go any further.

**UPDATE --**

It looks like the real issue is from this error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract': Native library (linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path`

After looking around a lot, I don't see a convenient place to find this `libtesseract.so` file, and I'm not sure what it takes to get this onto my Linux app server. I read that maybe I need to download some C++ runtime, but I don't see a Linux download for that. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Or is this something to do with a symbolic link?

Answer (score 5):

The Fix was simple for me,just do sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr from the command line. For linux you dont need to worry about the DDL librarires or the jvm version. Installing tessearct from apt-get will do the trick.

Comment: Yeah looking back, the issue (I think) was I was using `yum` package manager (on some kind of RedHat or something), and tesseract-ocr was not a convenient download. Recalling, it was a nightmare to get it to work without having it available through package management. I definitely think switching to Ubuntu or something debian (with `apt-get`) makes life a lot easier to get tesseract working...

Answer (score 2):

Tess4J should include required libraries. However, you need to extract them first.

This should do the trick:

```
File tmpFolder = LoadLibs.extractTessResources("win32-x86-64"); // replace platform
System.setProperty("java.library.path", tmpFolder.getPath());
```

You should replace the argument of `extractTessResources(..)` with your platform. You can find possible options by looking into the Tess4J jar file.

This way you need not to install Tesseract on your system.

Recently I wrote a [blog post about Tess4J](https://www.mscharhag.com/java/ocr-tess4j) in which I used this technique. Maybe it can help if you need further information or a running example project.

Answer (score 1):

Those DLLs are for Windows. For Linux, you'll need to install or [build](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling) from [Tesseract source](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout).

That GS version, 8.70, is quite old. The latest Ghost4J library that Tess4J uses is not compatible with that.

Comment: is it possible to specify a different version when executing `yum install ghostscript`? otherwise, what is the simplest way to install GhostScript on Linux without `yum install`? p.s. thank you for so actively helping those trying to work with Tess4J here on SO and other places

Comment: Looks like you have to [build](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Make.htm#Unix_build) it from the [source](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/), if the latest is not available from the repository.

Comment: I switched from a Red Hat distro to Ubuntu and it made the process **so** much easier to install tesseract and ghostscript. `apt-get install tesseract` got tesseract 3.03 setup and working, and `apt-get install ghostscript` got ghostscript  9.10 working fine. Dumb question: if tesseract is installed and working on its own, and ghostscript, do I only need the JAR's from Tess4J? (and not the traineddata, tessdata folder, DLL's, other stuff)

Comment: Yes, you do. Make sure to use a compatible version with your Tesseract version.

Comment: from my experience on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, all I needed to do was `apt-get install tesseract-ocr` and `ghostscript`. Then, I pointed TESSDATA_PREFIX env variable to the proper directory `apt-get` installed tesseract to (but I still needed to setDataPath on my Tess4J instance, even though the env var existed...). Then I included the JAR's that came with Tess4J's download (tess4j, ghostscript, log4j, imageio) on the class path... and that's all it took to get working. So it seems `apt-get install tesseract-ocr` got me the proper DLL's, and eng.traineddata...

Comment: Proper `.so`, not `.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

download test data by git

```
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata
```

Comment: It is not clear how your answer addresses the question. Why will downloading test data correct resource not found in path?

Comment: It installs tesseract that contains the library in question and adds it to the library path afaik.